# Entity Framework navigation property custom naming

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

When setting up a connection between two entities using Entity Framework (code first), I find it hard to handle naming of properties.

In the following code sample, it will not find the proper connection and will ask for a column named `airline_iata_airline_code` which does not exist and therefore it fails even though I setup the foreign key property (gave it the class name of the related class) and defined the column name to look for in the other class.

```
[ForeignKey("AirlineDto")]
[Column("iata_airline_code")]
public string IataAirlineCode { get; set; }
```

This does not work, but if I change it to the following sample, it finds the relation and returns the proper data from the database (not the name change).

```
[ForeignKey("AirlineDto")]
[Column("iata_airline_code")]
public string AirlineIataAirlineCode { get; set; }
```

The problem is that I do not want it to be called `<RelatedClass><PrimaryKey>`. I want to be able to define my own name. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if you using Code First or not but try the following on your DBConext class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourClassName>().Property(x => x.IataAirlineCode).HasColumnName("iata_airline_code");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is code first - I will update the question and try your suggestion :)

Comment: Sorry, it is the same result:
`Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column g.airline_iata_airline_code does not exist`

Comment: Okay there is additional information from this error message. It looks like you are not using Microsoft SQL Server but you using Npgsql, is that correct? The other thing I will like to know is the version of Entity Framework you using, is it EF Core? What nuget package you using for EF integration with Npgsql?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/navigation-property-with-code-first-navigation-property-in-ef/

As I could not get the custom naming to work by adding the foreign key attribute to the variable I changed the approach and added it to the navigation property. Both methods was explained on the site.

The working sample looks like this:

```
// Relations
public string IataAirlineCode { get; set; }

// Navigation
[ForeignKey("IataAirlineCode")]
public AirlineDto Airline { get; set; }
```

Comment: When applied to FK property, `ForeignKey` attribute must specify the navigation property name, not type. So in your original example, `[ForeignKey("Airline")] ` will also work.